# log4j2 runtime reconfiguration not working - empty file created

Tags: log4j2

I am trying to manually reconfigure log4j2 at runtime but getting partial success.

Here is the relevant code:

```java
package examples.test;

public class ABCImpl implements XYX{

    static Logger logger;

public void initialize(){
    LoggerContext ctx = null;
    Configuration config =  null;
    Map mp = null;

    ctx = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
        config = (Configuration)ctx.getConfiguration();
    mp = config.getAppenders();
    System.out.println("***<Provider o/p follows> Before logger re-configuration:");
        System.out.println("\tAppenders:" + mp.keySet());

    //reconfiguration attempt - starts
    try{
        URI configuration = this.getClass().getResource("/log4j2.xml").toURI();
        ctx  = Configurator.initialize(this.getClass().getName(), null, configuration);
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("\t-------Exception encountered-------");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

        config = (Configuration) ctx.getConfiguration();
    mp = config.getAppenders();
    System.out.println("***<Provider o/p follows> After logger re-configuration:");
    System.out.println("\tAppenders:" + mp.keySet());

    //reconfiguration attempt - ends

    logger = LogManager.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());
}

public void myBusinessMethod(){
        logger.info("Entry..............");
        logger.info("Exit..............");
    }
}
```

This class is actually part of a jar file and am running it inside an application server which guarantees that my `initialize` method would be called as soon as my class is instantiated.

Here is my log4j2.xml, which I have packed into jar's root:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <!-- Don't forget to set system property
    -DLog4jContextSelector=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerContextSelector
    to make all loggers asynchronous. -->

<Configuration status="info">
    <Appenders>
    <!-- Async Loggers will auto-flush in batches, so switch off immediateFlush. -->
        <RollingRandomAccessFile name="Appender1" fileName="servers/${sys:weblogic.Name}/logs/Auditing_${sys:weblogic.Name}.log" immediateFlush="true" append="false" filePattern="servers/${sys:weblogic.Name}/logs/archive/Auditing_${sys:weblogic.Name}-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}-%i.log.gz">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m %ex%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true"/>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="250 MB"/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="20"/>
        </RollingRandomAccessFile>
        <Async name="Async1">
            <AppenderRef ref="Appender1"/>
        </Async>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="examples.test.ABCImpl" level="info" includeLocation="false" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="Appender1"/>
        </Logger>
        <Root level="info" includeLocation="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="Appender1"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

The problem is even though the log file gets created, but nothing gets logged in it. The output in std out that I get is :

```
ABCImpl.initialize
        activeHandlerEntries.length=1
***<Provider o/p follows> Before logger re-configuration:
        Appenders:[Console]
***<Provider o/p follows> After logger re-configuration:
        Appenders:[Async1, Appender1]
```

Just to make sure that my `log4j2.xml` and the piece of code is okay without runtime reconfiguration stuff, if I use `-Dlog4j.configurationFile=file:SOME_PATH_OUTSIDE_JAR/log4j2.xml` log gets populated as expected.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Hours of helpless staring at the code and trying my hands here and there, I found that if I get the `Logger` from newly initialized context (which is obtained from `Configurator.initialize`) instead of `LogManager`, log gets populated with data.

Without this trick, not sure if I needed to call any additional API methods (just after `Configurator.initialize`)  to hook the new context into `LogManager` so that I could have continued traditional approach of getting `Logger` from `LogManager`.

```java
...
    config = (Configuration) ctx.getConfiguration();
    mp = config.getAppenders();
    System.out.println("***<Provider o/p follows> After logger re-configuration:");
    System.out.println("\tAppenders:" + mp.keySet());

    //reconfiguration attempt - ends


    //Following line screwed me up for over three weeks
    //logger = LogManager.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());

    //workaround:
    logger = ctx.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());
}

public void myBusinessMethod(){
    logger.info("Entry..............");
    logger.info("Exit..............");
}
....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I wondered, if deriving the context for initialization by

```
ctx = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
```

may be the problem, since you have to access the "current" context with

```
ctx = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(true);
```

according to [the Log4j2 API](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/LogManager.html#getContext%28boolean%29). I would really appreciate a clarification, since i'm trying to programmatically configuring Log4J2, too.

Comment: It is a best practice to set it to false in application server environment where different applications and even the application server itself might be using log4j. Per my understanding, setting it to true one might end up re-configuring/writing into loggers of other applications or application server depending on how they inturn have obtained the context.

Comment: And yes, tested and found that if I set it to true then entries into logger (= LogManager.getLogger(.......)) get logged into re-configured log as desired. But I think this is unsafe in application server environment.

Comment: Thanks - i'll get back on that post when having time to revisit the logging code. :)